# How do I get a reference to the Screens collection in VB Express 8?

Tags: vb.net, screen, screens

I've tried this example directly from MSDN:

Dim Screens() As System.Windows.Forms.Screens

and I can't find a way to get a reference to the Screen.  I've checked my references and they seem fine but I may have missed something.  Anyone experience this or know of a bug?

EDIT 0:  It helps if you're using the correct project type.  In WPF, it's SystemParameters.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you actually want

```
Dim Screens() As System.Windows.Forms.Screen
```

(no `s` at the end), as there isn't a `Screens` type. The above line declares `Screens` as an array of `Screen` objects - now you can do

```
Screens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens
```

and do whatever it is you want to do with each `Screen`.

*edit* not sure what reference problem you are still getting. From scratch, I start a new Windows Forms project, replace the code-behind in `Form1` with this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim Screens() As System.Windows.Forms.Screen
        Screens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens

        For Each s As Screen In Screens
            MessageBox.Show(s.DeviceName)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

and it runs and does what I expect. This is VS2005 (not Express) but I can't imagine that would make a difference.

Comment: Thanks AakashM, but no joy.  I've tried several variations and I can't find a reference.

Comment: I tried the same thing from scratch and still no luck...  I'm going to re-install.  It can't anything else?!?

Comment: @Brad. Is it definitely a Windows Forms project?